# Qt / C++ - Monitor specified input without focus

Tags: c++, qt, input

I want to be able to press a specific Qt::Key at any time regardless of focus. For example, ctrl+shift+F activates a method that brings the window back into focus.

I've done google searches for how to monitor input without focus in qt but I can't find anything.

Comment: No. There is no valid solution there, as QEvent's do not have a .key() or .modifiers() etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here after further searching:
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/35192

I didn't know they were referring to as 'global' hotkeys so I was essentially describing in google search.

I will elaborate since the code linked there isn't accurate (had to tweak a lot).

This is my current code:

```
#define MOD_NOREPEAT 0x4000
#define MOD_CTRL 0x0002
#define MOD_ALT 0x0001
#define MOD_SHIFT 0x0004

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, MOD_ALT | MOD_SHIFT | MOD_NOREPEAT, 0x46);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Interface w;
    w.show();

    a.processEvents();

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if(w.isClosing)
            return msg.wParam;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        if(msg.message == WM_HOTKEY)
        {
            if(msg.wParam == 1)
                qDebug() << "Hot Key activated: HOME";
        }
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

The a.processEvents will make your QApplication continue processing events regardless of the while loop. When I exited the program it wouldn't kill because of the loop running in main, so now I check for a bool from the `Interface` class that overrides `closeEvent` as such:
`void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *);`

And in class file:

```
void Interface::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *)
{
    isClosing = true;
}
```

The only downside is hex codes for hotkeys. If anyone has a solution please let me know. 0x46 is F.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this either by subclassing QApplication and overriding its `event(QEvent *)` method, or (more commonly) by calling `qApp->installEventFilter(someObject)`, where (someObject) is some Qt object (whichever one is most convenient for you) whose `eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *)` method you have overridden with your own implementation that watches for the appropriate QKeyEvent and does the appropriate action in response.

Comment: How do I get the key from the QEvent? It will provide the type of event but not which key is being pressed during it. I have an eventfilter and a keypressevent but how do I make the eventfilter listen to the keypressevent when not in focus?

Comment: Found it, thanks. `static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event)->key() == Qt::Key_A`

Comment: I was too hasty to mark it correct. It doesn't receive any events at all when not in focus.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not implemented in Qt. You can use [Qxt](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/Home). Qxt is an extension library for Qt providing a suite of cross-platform utility classes to add functionality not readily available in Qt. It has Global Shortcut (hot keys) which detects key presses even if the application is minimized or hidden.

After compiling Qxt, link your application to it by adding these to your .pro :

```
CONFIG += qxt
QXT = core gui
```

And include `QxtGlobalShortcut` :

```
#include <QxtGlobalShortcut>
```

Example usage :

```
QxtGlobalShortcut* shortcut = new QxtGlobalShortcut(window);
connect(shortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), window, SLOT(toggleVisibility()));
shortcut->setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+Shift+F"));
```

Comment: It's configure script fails to compile. That's the first part of the process. Error is `Project ERROR: No module matching library 'QxtCore' found.` so it's nothing to do with my paths etc., until they fix their software this isn't a viable solution.

Comment: I think if you clone the latest source code (Not the release branch) you can compile it.

Comment: Yea it got past configure, but it still wont make but that doesn't matter, their website says it wont work with later versions and it is no longer maintained. They recommend pulling out the components you need but that isn't working either. At this point I've wasted a couple of hours with no result for something extremely common (running a method when a key is pressed), the app not being in focus shouldn't matter because there's a LOT of applications that have hotkeys that work when the app isn't in focus.

Comment: You are right it is so simple but unfortunately Qt does not have this feature. You can see the implementation of `QxtGlobalShortcut` and just add that part to your code.

Comment: Tried doing that now. It's not working. `error: C2491: 'QxtGlobalShortcut::staticMetaObject' : definition of dllimport static data member not allowed` along with 15 warnings about `inconsistent dll linkage`. I can elaborate by editing original question, but that's the gist of it. The reality is I can only barely fix my own programs, there's no way I can fix theirs. I have an idea of what it means, but definitely not how to fix it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to help, upvoted because it will do what people looking here will want it to if they can get things running, as I said it's a bit beyond me to get other people's things going since I'm still very much learning; found an alternative less desirable method for the time being, will come back to this in the future.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to detect a pressed key outside the window. You only need to use the built-in Windows libraries. You can read how to do it in [this article](https://scythe-studio.com/pl/blog/how-to-track-keyboard-usage-on-windows-with-qt-in-2020). Unfortunately, it's not that simple on the Unix systems currently.